# qgis 1.8.0 crash when starting qthread

Tags: qgis, layers, multithreading

I am trying to update a vector layer attribute table using QThread.
i connect a pushbutton click with a slot to start the thread:

def EGSupdateAttributeTable(self):
    AttUpdateEGSThread = EGSUpdateAttThread(self.theLayerToEdit)
AttUpdateEGSThread.start()

and this is my thread class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import sys
import qgis.utils

#the update EGS Algorithme attribute table Class
class EGSUpdateAttThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,theLayerToEdit):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.theLayerToEdit = theLayerToEdit
        self.LayerFeatureCount = self.theLayerToEdit.featureCount()
    def run(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, 'layer', str(self.LayerFeatureCount))
        #self.editScenarioDlg.ui.PrbUpdateAtt.show()
        provider = self.theLayerToEdit.dataProvider()
        #allAttrs = provider.attributeIndexes()
        Feature = QgsFeature()
        allAttrs = provider.attributeIndexes()
        provider.select(allAttrs)
        iFloodProt = provider.fieldNameIndex("FloodProt")
        indexStableClimate = provider.fieldNameIndex("StableClim")      
        iUsableWat = provider.fieldNameIndex("usablewat")
        iACRE = provider.fieldNameIndex("ACRES")
        immwater = provider.fieldNameIndex("mmwater")
        iCN = provider.fieldNameIndex("CN")
        iCarbonFixe = provider.fieldNameIndex("CarbonFixe")
        iDenitrific = provider.fieldNameIndex("Denitrific")
        iWaterRetentionValue = self.editScenarioDlg.ui.leWaterRetValue.text().toInt()[0]
        iStableClimate = self.editScenarioDlg.ui.leDollByCarbonValue.text().toInt()[0]
        iUsableWater = self.editScenarioDlg.ui.leDollByNitrogenValue.text().toInt()[0]
        while provider.nextFeature(Feature):
            if len(Feature.attributeMap())>0:
                #QMessageBox.information(self.drawShapeDlg, 'attributetable' ,  str(Feature.attributeMap()))
                dACREVal =  Feature.attributeMap()[iACRE].toDouble()[0]
                immwaterVal =  Feature.attributeMap()[immwater].toInt()[0]
                #QMessageBox.information(self.drawShapeDlg, 'iWaterRetentionValue' ,  str(iWaterRetentionValue))
                dCNValue = Feature.attributeMap()[iCN].toDouble()[0]
                dCarbonFixeValue =  Feature.attributeMap()[iCarbonFixe].toDouble()[0]
                dDenitrificValue = Feature.attributeMap()[iDenitrific].toDouble()[0]
                dFloodProtVal = iWaterRetentionValue * (dACREVal * 43560) * immwaterVal *  0.00328084
                dStableClim = dCarbonFixeValue * iStableClimate
                dUsableWater = dDenitrificValue * iUsableWater

                self.theLayerToEdit.changeAttributeValue(Feature.id(), iFloodProt, QVariant(dFloodProtVal) )
                self.theLayerToEdit.changeAttributeValue(Feature.id(), indexStableClimate, QVariant(dStableClim))
                self.theLayerToEdit.changeAttributeValue(Feature.id(), iUsableWat, QVariant(dUsableWater))
```

i cannot identify the cause of this crash

Comment: I'll take a guess: something GUI on the non-GUI thread. Try removing the QMessageBox bits in run()